Setup cypress tests in azure devOps for a CI project with 2 repos(one for main app and one for cypress tests)?
We have an azure DevOps CI project with separate repos for development code of our web app and cypress tests.
I need to create a test pipeline that runs whenever there are changes to the main branch of the web app repo. How do I achieve this since the tests are in a different repo?
I am having a hard time to do this since I am new to the CI pipelines in Azure and also to Cypress.
I would also like to display a widget in azure or some visual representation of the passed/ failed test cases once the run is complete. Could someone help me setup cypress and to display the results? Thanks in advance.


I need to create a test pipeline that runs whenever there are changes to the main branch of the web app repo

You can create a pipeline based on your test repo and add your "web app" repo as a repo resource. Add branch filter to control that the pipeline will only be triggered when there is commit from main branch.
trigger: none

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: webapprepo
      type: git
      name: <your-project-name>/webapprepo
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
          - main


I would also like to display a widget in azure or some visual representation of the passed/ failed test cases once the run is complete.

Add a PublishTestResults@2 task to publish your test result to the build summary page.
For example,
      - script: |
          npm install -g wait-on
          npm run start:e2e & wait-on $(hosturl) & npm run cy:run-junit-reporter:e2e && npm run cy:run-junit-reporter:component
        continueOnError: False
        displayName: 'Run tests'

      - task: PublishTestResults@2
        displayName: "Publish test results"
        inputs:
          testResultsFormat: "JUnit"
          testResultsFiles: "$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/cypress/results/result-*.xml"
          testRunTitle: "$(Build.BuildNumber)"
          searchFolder: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)"
          mergeTestResults: true

Then see the test result from the build summary page:

